# TypeError: The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a coroutine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am working on flask and MongoDB to create and start AWS EC2 instances and log that for different users. But when I try to call a function that I wrote to retrieve a document, this error is returned:

> TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a coroutine.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\vishn\.virtualenvs\GameFlow-backend(flask)-QWbAV1pw\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\vishn\.virtualenvs\GameFlow-backend(flask)-QWbAV1pw\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\vishn\.virtualenvs\GameFlow-backend(flask)-QWbAV1pw\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\vishn\.virtualenvs\GameFlow-backend(flask)-QWbAV1pw\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "C:\Users\vishn\.virtualenvs\GameFlow-backend(flask)-QWbAV1pw\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1535, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
File "C:\Users\vishn\.virtualenvs\GameFlow-backend(flask)-QWbAV1pw\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1727, in make_response
    raise TypeError( TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple,
Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a coroutine.
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2021 08:37:23] "GET /dashboard?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2021 08:37:23] "GET /dashboard?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2021 08:37:23] "GET /dashboard?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2021 08:37:23] "GET /dashboard?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2021 08:37:23] "GET /dashboard?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

My DB code is:

```
client = motor.AsyncIOMotorClient(MONGO_DETAILS)

database = client['vm-data']
db = database


async def create_user(data_value: dict):
    new_value = await db["vm-form"].insert_one(data_value)
    created_value = await db["vm-form"].find_one({"_id": new_value.inserted_id})
    print(created_value)
    return created_value


async def retrieve_data(data_id):
    data_val = await db['vm-form'].find_one({'email': data_id})
    return data_val


async def update_data(id):
    data_val = await db['vm-form'].update_one()
```

And function from where I am calling is:

```
async def dashboard():
    data_val = session[constants.PROFILE_KEY]
    email = data_val['email']
    user_name = data_val['name']
    response = await retrieve_data(email)
    instance_state = response['instance_state']
    if instance_state == 'running':
        return render_template('dashboard.html',
                               userinfo=session[constants.PROFILE_KEY], vm_data='Hydrogen', vm_type='Windows Instance',
                               userinfo_pretty=json.dumps(session[constants.JWT_PAYLOAD], indent=4))
    else:
        return render_template('dashboard.html',
                               userinfo=session[constants.PROFILE_KEY],
                               userinfo_pretty=json.dumps(session[constants.JWT_PAYLOAD], indent=4))
```

I am not sure if this is enough data to solve the error but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also any suggestions on how to go about checking if the user has access to an instance(like I am trying to do in the dashboard function) would be awesome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please post the full error traceback

Comment: Hi @WillDaSilva I have edited the question to add the traceback. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've got it to work.
It worked when I put the requires_auth header above the @app.route() (which I forgot to add in the question).

Comment: Where did you put it?